# How can I reassociate a Docker volume with a container after docker system prune?

Tags: docker

I ran `docker system prune`, forgetting about a particular Postgres database whose contents I still wanted.

I think I probably still have the volume in macOS's Docker virtual machine. However, I have no idea which it is, they all look like:

```
✗ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     0bb96275a994e1eacafe016547a194d8f91580eb2b42e47897f4c90b48f7f92a
local     1a5adc7281788533e612b8c11cede2847aaf3f9819678322950ba4c199711481
local     1a6f07dd7a704731d0ad42e57a95d6ea136951c47de6e28aa3d2b8d8d891bf4f
local     2ad31cdc84c0e606e4535b1e22c9826fdf7cf21772cdb3c1604179aea6f861ff
[70 more volumes not listed]
```

My questions: How can I launch a Docker container from the `postgres:9.6-alpine` image I was using for the application, and have it use one of those volumes to check if it's the one I am looking for?

The database container was previously created by `docker-compose`. If I can launch the whole application with `docker-compose` and have the database use a particular volume, I can quite quickly discover if it's the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Basic loop

This little bash loop will run though all the volumes, mounting them into a temporary container and printing its contents:

```bsh
for vol in $(docker volume ls --format "{{.Name}}"); do \
  echo "$vol ======================================"; \
  docker run --rm -v $vol:/tmp debian:buster ls /tmp; \
  echo '------------------------------------------'; \
done
```

## Include a `grep` in the loop

To simplify search over 70 volumes, you can add `grep` to the command in the loop so that it only prints stuff that matches the pattern:

```bsh
docker run --rm -v $vol:/tmp debian:buster ls /tmp | grep pg_; \
```

This way you will see only files with `pg_` in name and that should be enough to find Postgres volumes.

## Interact with the database in the loop

Suppose that you still have many results, and need to inspect database tables to find the right volume, you could do:

```bsh
docker run -v $vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data --rm -u postgres postgres:9.6-alpine bash -c 'source /docker-entrypoint.sh; docker_temp_server_start; psql -U postgres db -c "\d"; docker_temp_server_stop; exit'
```

This:

- creates a container based on `postgres:9.6-alpine` with the volume attached
- starts the entrypoint script (that starts up the Postgres engine)
- runs a `psql` command to list the tables of the database `db`

## Recovering the volume

Once you found the right volume, you start PostgreSQL container with it like this:

```bsh
docker run -v volume_name:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.6-alpine
```

You can then interact with it in the usual way. For example, use `docker ps` to get the name of the container, then:

```bsh
docker exec -i <name of container> pg_dump -U postgres -F c db > database.dump
```

to dump the database.

Comment: That is really great, thanks. It has immediately reduced the list of candidates to 50.

Comment: What I am trying to do next is to use the command to run: `psql -U postgres db -c "\d"`, to see the names of tables, which will pinpoint the exact one I want.

Comment: `docker run --rm -v $vol:/tmp postgres:9.6-alpine psql -U postgres db -c "\d";`  doesn't work in the script because the `psql` overrides the default behaviour, in which Postgres starts up, so it can't find a database to query.

Comment: @DanieleProcida That is a bit harder that just list folder contents, you have to spin up the database, query it and then shut it down to proceed to the next item in loop. I can help you with it a bit later but you must know that there is a __*risk of data corruption*__ on other volumes, where there is something except the database you are looking for.

Comment: @DanieleProcida here is, as promised, a command to start the database and execute `psql`: `docker run -v $vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data --rm -u postgres postgres:9.6-alpine bash -c 'source /docker-entrypoint.sh; docker_temp_server_start; psql -d postgres -c "\l"; docker_temp_server_stop; exit' \ `. Adjust the `psql` part as you like.

Comment: Lo! and the database was all recovered. @anemyte I cannot thank you enough. For completeness I will write up what I did into your answer for future reference.

Comment: I made the edit to the answer with the additional information a couple of days ago, but it has yet to be reviewed.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Turned out I was able to approve it. Thanks!